# JMeter gets 504 gateway timeouts but no errors on Azure App insights

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-application-insights, load-testing, http-status-code-504

I am running a load test on JMeter, and I have a test case like: 300 users in 10 sec (rump-up) and I got a 504 - gateway timeout error. The endpoint is exposed on Azure (app service plan, PostgreSQL, SignalR). I was analyzing data on Application insights, but it doesn't show errors at all, how is that possible? On the App service plan, I can see some faulted connections but how can I identify why I get a 504 error?

Comment: I have created a sample app service in azure portal -> After that Goto `Advance tools` and click on `Go` [image1](https://i.imgur.com/QWzrTC8.png) ->select `Site Extensions` [image2](https://i.imgur.com/4uU0bvu.png) -> [image3](https://i.imgur.com/XybTuaf.png) -> Set the values and click on `Update` [image4](https://i.imgur.com/mIS6452.png) -> restart the web app -> open jmeter [image5](https://i.imgur.com/i9T9VXl.png) -> final out put [image6](https://i.imgur.com/PMTIYiw.png)

Answer (score 0):

- I have created a sample App Service in azure portal and followed the below steps
- After creating App service Goto **Advanced tools** -> click on **Go**

[image]

- Then Click on **Site Extensions**

[image]

- Goto **Gallery** and Search for **Dynamic** and click on search -> click on **+** and click on ok

[image]

- Set the values as below and click on **update Settings**

[image]

- After updating the setting restart the app service

[image]

- Set the users and the time according to the setting you have updated in app service

[image]

- Copy the App service link and open JMeter as use the link as below

[image]

- This is the output we got when you performed the above steps

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to put restrictions, I need to identify why I have a 504 error, what is a bottleneck? I tried like you explained but I don't have that option, I have: Environment, SSH, Bash and Log stream.

Comment: The fourth picture in the answer check the exact settings in your app service the third check box is ticked or not if it is ticked, please untick the check box it will Thow 504 error.

Comment: When the browser sent an HTTP request to the server, it did not receive a response from upstream server in time to complete the request. When you encounter the 504 Bad Gateway error, it will usually look something like this: This HTTP error can appear in different forms and various error messages across browsers, servers, and operating systems.