# How to set dynamic IP Security in Azure app service

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-web-app-service

```
<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity enableLoggingOnlyMode="false" enableProxyMode="true">
    <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="10" />
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="30" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="500" />
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
  <ipSecurity enableProxyMode="true" allowUnlisted="false" >
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress="1.2.3.4" subnetMask="255.255.255.255" />
  </ipSecurity>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The Web App consists of ASP.NET 6. With this definition, if 10 requests were made at the same time, more than 11 requests were expected to be rejected at 403. However, I started 100 concurrent threads in Apache Meter and made 50 repeated requests, but never 403. Is there a mistake in the definition?

Comment: Go through the [So-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878703/jmeter-gets-504-gateway-timeouts-but-no-errors-on-azure-app-insights/74898535#74898535) it might solve your problem this is applicable for windows only not for linux.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/denybyconcurrentrequests):

> To support blocking a client on your Web server by the number of concurrent requests, you must install the IP and Domain Restrictions role service.

so you need to make sure that the above roles are installed and active.

With regards to JMeter ensure that you're not running it in [Distributed Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) and [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-blazemeter) is not activated by any means.